# from VBA to VB.Net / c#

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, vba, excel

A language learning question.

I am very proficient in Excel VBA programming. Lately, I was requested to learn a new language relatively quick so that I can build a standalone application (in Windows).

I can use the most popular ones like C#, VB.Net, Java or C++ to build that application.

Can you suggest, given my background in VBA, which language shall I pursue to learn in order to achieve this goal in the shortest time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, which one has a name most like the one you are currently using?

Comment: Should this be in programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: Normally I would say VB.NET, but VB.NET is clearly a dying technology.  Most .NET developers use C#.  The advantage is that there are many resources for C#.  You can almost always find good examples for what you want to do.  That is not always the case for other programming languages.

Comment: This question is highly subjective and not suitable for stack overflow. I've voted to close as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm going to say can sound crazy, but it's my experience: if you know vba, don't go to vb .net.

I was an VB 4/5/6 programmer, and when .net came i tried it. It was a nightmare. Why? Because everything is very similar but not just the same, you will have a lot of troubles with bad habits, triying to do what you know to do (what in vb .net must not be done, hehehe) and so on.

Between C#, Java or C++, there is your preferences. C# is more Microsoft mentality, so you will not be so lost as with Java comming from vba, and if you are targeting MS platform is one of the best choices (also for mobile dev, Xamarin does a great job porting c# to Android and iOS), but Java has more laboral opportunities (more servers with linux). C++ is a lot more powerful, but also a lot more complicated and developing a program with it is really slow compared to any of the other ones.

So, if you can, learn all of them, start with C# or Java (both are very similar) and in the future expand your knowledge to C++.